# Cannot connect to aws ec2 instance with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I launched ec2 instance and nginx on it. I can connect to it with http and ssh, but cannot with https.
I referenced [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) to configure my setup and got this:

ACL settings

```
inbound rules
Rule number |   Type   |Protocol|Port|  Source |Allow/Deny
1           | HTTP(80) | TCP(6) | 80 |0.0.0.0/0| Allow
2           |HTTPS(443)| TCP(6) |443 |0.0.0.0/0| Allow
3           |  SSH(22) | TCP(6) | 22 |0.0.0.0/0| Allow
4           |HTTPS(443)| TCP(6) |443 |   ::/0  | Allow
*           |Alltraffic|  ALL   |ALL |0.0.0.0/0| Deny   (AWS default)

outbound rules
Rule number |   Type   |Protocol|Port|  Source |Allow/Deny
1           |Alltraffic|  ALL   |ALL |0.0.0.0/0| Allow
2           |Alltraffic|  ALL   |ALL |   ::/0  | Allow
*           |Alltraffic|  ALL   |ALL |0.0.0.0/0| Deny   (AWS default)
```

Security group

```
inbound rules
   Type   |Protocol|Port|  Source 
HTTPS(443)| TCP(6) |443 |0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS(443)| TCP(6) |443 |   ::/0  
  SSH(22) | TCP(6) | 22 |0.0.0.0/0
 HTTP(80) | TCP(6) | 80 |0.0.0.0/0

outbound rules
   Type   |Protocol|Port|  Source 
Alltraffic|  ALL   |ALL |0.0.0.0/0
Alltraffic|  ALL   |ALL |   ::/0
```

If i run Reachability Analyzer from internet gateway to instance with 80 port, its Reachable

If i run Reachability Analyzer from internet gateway to instance with 433 port, i got message

`Network ACL <acl> does not allow inbound traffic`

Why its does not allow traffic and how to fix it ?

Comment: simple question... does nginx listen on 443? maybe it isn't EC2 at all?

Comment: Have you launched your instance in default vpc Or custom vpc?

Comment: Nginx listen 80 and 443 port, http connection working, https not.
Instance launched it in default vpc

Comment: I tried to open all ports and protocols in acl and in security group, and https working now, but its not looking secure

Comment: You should definitely limit access via the Security Group, but there is no need to use the Network ACL to limit access. If that isn't working, please add details at the bottom of your question to show the current configuration and the results of the Reachability Analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there should never be a need to modify the Network ACLs (NACLs) unless you have a specific network requirement (eg a DMZ).

They should be left at their default "Allow All" for both Inbound and Outbound traffic.

Given that the error message says "Network ACL  does not allow inbound traffic", I recommend that you set the NACLs back to the default of "Allow All". That will resolve the error that you are receiving.

Comment: Its typo when copy table from aws web interface to plain text. Actually, i don't specify port, i picked https from list, so it's 443 actually.

Comment: Okay. I recommend that you reset the NACLs back to the default "Allow All" settings.

Comment: He allowed the specific protocols @YakovAkimov, but the "deny" to all traffics seems to have made it implicit. That's correct, right, John?